# IFileProvider returning 01/01/0001 for last modified date of all files in Physical Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In startup I have set my IFileProvider in configure services as follows:

```
            IFileProvider physicalProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Directory.GetParent(env.ContentRootPath).ToString());
        services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(physicalProvider);
```

Now when I go to use to find the files last modified date in my controller I get date 01/01/0001 for all files. My code is as follows:

```
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment env;
    private IFileProvider _fileProvider;
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public MainReviewController(LoginDBContext context, IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env, IFileProvider fileProvider)
    {
        _context = context;
        connectionString = configuration["ConnectionStrings:DBContext"];
        this.env = env;
        _fileProvider = fileProvider;
    }
```

After I use dependency injection to use the file provider I use the following code in my post request

```
                    var rootPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(env.ContentRootPath).ToString(), "ARMSFiles");

                foreach (var file in mainreviewdocuments)
                {
                    var filePath = Path.Combine(rootPath, file.DOCUMENT_FULL_PATH);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(filePath);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_fileProvider.GetFileInfo(filePath).LastModified);
                }
```

Any ideas on this? In my startup i use dependency injection as well to ensure i am using the same env variable as my controller so the directories should line up. It is basically a folder outside of my root folder since that is a bit more secure and I use it for a webdav when I actually deploy this.

Comment: The `filePath`  is a `folder` or `file`?

Comment: file path is the complete filepath so C:\inetpub\files\sampledoc.docx

Comment: @Jason Pan Any ideas?

Comment: I have test the usage of `_fileProvider` in my local, and it works well. If the file doesn't exist, the value of `LastModified` equal `01/01/0001` should be expected behavior.

Comment: FileProvider uses _relative_ file paths; it's a rooted virtual file system, after all. And you generally shouldn't reach outside of the web applications root folder, which is something you seem to be doing. Is the problem just with LastModified or everything (as I'd suspect)? Does your application's user have access to the files folder? Does it work when you _don't_ use file provider? Why are you creating the file provider at the _parent_ of your content root path?

Comment: The issue was the relative path as you indicated. I was using absolute in the parameter of the GetFileInfo() which was wrong so file was not there. Based on your comment is this bad practice even if I have a webdav server running on IIS? I figured it was best to do the webdav folder outside of the wwwroot folder since that is specific to the web server. It is also set as a virtual path but I cannot remember why I did that exactly lol. Been a while since I set this up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use below code, and get the value of `LastModified`;

```
IDirectoryContents dirContents = _fileProvider.GetDirectoryContents("ARMSFiles");
IFileInfo fileInfo = _fileProvider.GetFileInfo("ARMSFiles/TextFile.txt");
```

**Test Result**

[image]

[image]

#### Test Code:

*Tips: below code just for test, pls don't use it in your production environment directly.*

**1. Test Method**

```
public IActionResult TestFileProvider()
{
    // the static root path, just for test
    string filePath = @"D:\M***e\F***e\TestCookie\ARMSFiles\TextFile.txt";

    IDirectoryContents dirContents = _fileProvider.GetDirectoryContents("ARMSFiles");
    IFileInfo fileInfo = _fileProvider.GetFileInfo("ARMSFiles/TextFile.txt");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(filePath);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fileInfo.LastModified);
    return Ok(fileInfo.LastModified);
}
```

**2. ConfigureServices Method**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //IFileProvider physicalProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Directory.GetParent(env.ContentRootPath).ToString());
    var physicalProvider = _env.ContentRootFileProvider;
    var embeddedProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
    var compositeProvider = new CompositeFileProvider(physicalProvider, embeddedProvider);
    services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(compositeProvider);
    ...
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

}
```

**3. Configure Method**

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ARMSFiles")),
        RequestPath = "/ARMSFiles"
    });
```

Comment: I realized my issue was the fact its a relative path once you initialize it in startup. I cannot believe i missed that in the MS docs. So our code now is the same so this is the correct answer. However, the only issue I have is when I publish my app to the IIS server and use this code the last modified date is forward by 4 hours. So even in IIS when i look at the file it shows last modified 1:53PM it shows it as 5:53PM. Any reason it would do this? Worked perfect in visual studio locally when testing on my local file system.

Comment: @Bradyboyy88 The time is different, this is obviously caused by the time difference between your local computer and the server. Maybe the time zone set on your computer is different from the time zone set on the server. The easiest way is to telnet to a folder on the server and check the last modification time.

Comment: Hey the server is local on my network and when remoting into the server the date is identical to my computer. Not sure why this LastModified() is returning a date 4 hours later? I have accepted your answer but I am still not sure why it is doing it.

Comment: @Bradyboyy88 may be you can create a new post,if someone familiar with the issue,they will tell you

Comment: Might be due to this (UTC vs LocalTime): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#model-binding-changes-in-aspnet-core-mvc-and-razor-pages